# finding out what HCL literals GCP roles map to

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have the following code:

```
resource "google_project_iam_binding" "px_kubernetes_engine_cluster_viewer" {
    project = var.project_id
    role    = "roles/kubernetesEngineCluster.viewer"
    members = [
        "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.px.email}",
    ]
}
```

My aim is to assign the Kubernetes Engine Cluster viewer role to a service account, however, whatever string literal represents this and I have tried: "roles/kubernetesEngineCluster.viewer" and "roles/kubernetesEngineClusterViewer" without success, the GCP provider does not like this.

How can I find out what Kubernetes Engine Cluster viewer maps to in HCL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The role is `roles/container.clusterViewer`.

The HCL supports the same definitions that Google Cloud IAM uses. For Kubernetes they are here:

[Predefined GKE Roles](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/iam#roles)

The CLI can list all predefined roles:

[gcloud iam roles list](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/iam/roles/list)

Comment: Many thanks, proves my GCP knowledge is a little rusty